# How to view SQLite data in ionicframework?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, sqlite

I am dealing with SQLite in my ionicframework project.

Every time I change the code in controller, I need to rerun the apps in my phone and see the console.log what was the output.

Anyone knows how to view SQLite in android / ios phone from PC?

> It was so hard and takes so much time to make any changes in codes and
>   to rerun the project to see the result in console.log

Any helps will make my coding faster. Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond what android device monitor provides to extract data ? You will need a separate tool to view the sqlite file.

Comment: Yes of course, I need something like third party software. If it could be live reload then it would be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--livereload` or `-l` in run command as mention in [ionic cli docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html)

Run your app using this command

```
ionic run android -l
```

or

```
ionic run android --livereload
```

Comment: Any thirdparty for sqlite software to view in ionic project?

Comment: you can use this firefox plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: Thanks for the info, how to ready directly to my phone? Any directories or what I need todo?